# Html request for Biwenger in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to scrape the data from Biwenger with an html request but the response is returning different data than if url is opened in chrome.

Here is my code

```
import requests

shots_url = "https://biwenger.as.com/user/naranjas-4537694"

response = requests.get(shots_url)
response.raise_for_status() # raise exception if invalid response

print(response.text)
```

I don't get any error () however the data request show different data than the data in the url and this message:

```
<!doctype html><meta charset=utf-8><title>Biwenger</title><base href=/ ><meta...<div class=body><p>Looks like the browser you're using is not compatible with Biwenger :(<p>We recommend using <a href=http://www.google.com/chrome/ target=_blank>Google Chrome</a>...</script>
```

Any idea what code I can use to get the right data?

If you require any more information please let me know. Thank you everyone.

Comment: what you would like to scrape from that link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript/JSON. When you open Firefox/Chrome developer tools - Network tab, you will see where the page is making requests).

This example will get the information about user players:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


user_data_url = 'https://biwenger.as.com/api/v2/user/4537694?fields=*,account(id),players(id,owner),lineups(round,points,count,position),league(id,name,competition,mode,scoreID),market,seasons,offers,lastPositions'
all_data_url = 'https://cf.biwenger.com/api/v2/competitions/la-liga/data?lang=en&score=1&callback=jsonp_xxx' # <--- check @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη answer, it's possible to do it without callback= parameter

response = requests.get(all_data_url)
data = json.loads( re.findall(r'jsonp_xxx\((.*)\)', response.text)[0] )

user_data = requests.get(user_data_url).json()

# pprint(user_data)  # <-- uncomment this to see user data
# pprint(data)       # <-- uncomment this to see data about all players

for p in user_data['data']['players']:
    pprint(data['data']['players'][str(p['id'])])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
    {'fantasyPrice': 22000000,
     'fitness': [10, 2, 2, 2, -2],
     'id': 599,
     'name': 'Pedro León',
     'playedAway': 8,
     'playedHome': 8,
     'points': 38,
     'pointsAway': 16,
     'pointsHome': 22,
     'pointsLastSeason': 16,
     'position': 3,
     'price': 1400000,
     'priceIncrement': 60000,
     'slug': 'pedro-leon',
     'status': 'ok',
     'teamID': 76}
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {'fantasyPrice': 9000000,
     'fitness': [None, 'injured', 'doubt', None, 2],
     'id': 1093,
     'name': 'Javi López',
     'playedAway': 4,
     'playedHome': 2,
     'points': 10,
     'pointsAway': 6,
     'pointsHome': 4,
     'pointsLastSeason': 77,
     'position': 2,
     'price': 210000,
     'priceIncrement': 0,
     'slug': 'javier-lopez',
     'status': 'ok',
     'teamID': 7}
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: you don't need all this big round since we are dealing with [JSONP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp) which just putted there to manage `cross-domain issues`, and it's already have stable key of `jsonp_1912703205`, Once it's removed so you will get `JSON dictionary` instead of `str`. check my posted answer

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη That I didn't know, so it's easier with your method - without `re` parsing. For sure the site has some official API, but I didn't bother to search for it :)

Comment: It’s actually same URL, check the difference ! I’ve just removed JSONP callback with its value

Comment: @AndrejKesely, where did you find this api? How could I scrape through the other information available in the game (i.e. Market transfers using the log in user)

Comment: @eltrompeta You should look in Firefox/Chrome developer tools (Network tab) and see, where the page is making requests. Usually you will see some JSON messages and URL from where this messages are coming from.

Comment: @eltrompeta Better will be using some API, eg. https://github.com/pablopb3/biwenger-api But google for "biwenger api" for more informations.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I will read it to see if I make it work. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import csv

r = requests.get(
    "https://cf.biwenger.com/api/v2/competitions/la-liga/data?lang=en&score=1").json()

data = []
for k, v in r['data']['players'].items():
    data.append(v.values())

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(v.keys())
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Output: [Click Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a29a16b3ccbe77be830cf96f25ab5794/output.csv)

[image]